# Build PyQt5 on Windows with OpenSSL support?

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl, pyqt5, qsslsocket

I'm trying to build PyQt5 with SSL support but, until now, I have no success at all.

What I have done:

- Rebuild Qt with OpenSSL Support: **OK**

  ```
  configure.exe -static -debug-and-release -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop -platform win32-g++ -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssleay32 -llibeay32" -I C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -L C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib

  mingw32-make
  ```
- Install SIP: **OK**

  ```
  python configure.py -p win32-g++
  mingw32-make
  mingw32-make install
  ```
- Install PyQt5: **OK**

  ```
  python configure.py --spec=win32-g++
  mingw32-make
  mingw32-make install
  ```

  - Edit the `configure.py` file, adding a `'printsupport'` on QtWebKitWidgets ModuleMetadata:

    `'QtWebKitWidgets': ModuleMetadata(qmake_QT=['webkitwidgets', 'printsupport']),`

    instead of

    `'QtWebKitWidgets': ModuleMetadata(qmake_QT=['webkitwidgets']),`
  - After (or before?) the `mingw32-make`, remove the line

    `-strip C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)\Python34\pyuic5.bat`

    from target `install_pyuic5`:
- Test: **NOT OK**

  ```
  >>> from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QSslSocket
  >>> QSslSocket.supportsSsl()
  False
  ```

So, my questions are:

1. Am I doing anything wrong?
2. Is there any other configuration needed?

Why I'm asking that...If everything is "ok", I'm trying to access (with a QWebview) some `https` URLs and I'm getting lot or SSL erros, such as:

```
    QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
    QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
    QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
    QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

1. Download and Install the "Light" version of OpenSSL
2. Follow the above procedure to Rebuild Qt with OpenSSL support + Install SIP + Install PyQt
3. Copy `ssleay32.dll`, `libeay32.dll` and `libssl32.dll` to the Qt > mingw > bin folder (`C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin` in my case)

Now you can see a big `True` when you do a `QSslSocket.supportsSsl()` test.