# Python scraping of javascript web pages fails for https pages only

Tags: python, ssl, https, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 to scrape web pages, which works great for http:// URLs, but not at all for https:// URLs.

The relevant part of my script is below:

```
class WebPage(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__()

        self.timerScreen = QTimer()
        self.timerScreen.setInterval(2000)
        self.timerScreen.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timerScreen.timeout.connect(self.handleLoadFinished)

        self.loadFinished.connect(self.timerScreen.start)


    def start(self, urls):
        self._urls = iter(urls)
        self.fetchNext()

    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            url = next(self._urls)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        return True

    def processCurrentPage(self):
        url = self.mainFrame().url().toString()
        html = self.mainFrame().toHtml()

        #Do stuff with html
        print('loaded: [%d bytes] %s' % (self.bytesReceived(), url))

    def handleLoadFinished(self):
        self.processCurrentPage()
        if not self.fetchNext():
            qApp.quit()
```

For secure pages, the script returns a blank page. The only html coming back is `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`.

I'm at a bit of a loss. Is there a setting that I'm missing related to handling secure URLs?

Comment: do you mean "For secure pages, the script returns a blank page"?

Comment: Ah, yes I do. Thanks, I should have spotted that.

Comment: @samg86. I cannot reproduce this. Please provide some sample secure urls that cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows, please try this:
[Build PyQt5 on Windows with OpenSSL support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392247/build-pyqt5-on-windows-with-openssl-support)

Have you considered using [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) or [Scrapy.](https://scrapy.org/)

I have used Beautiful Soup for my project and it worked like a charm. It has SSL support too.

Answer (score 0):

tested with PyQt4 and normally opened pages with HTTPS

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

    def _result_available(self, ok):
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        print(frame.toHtml())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Browser()
    view.load(QUrl('https://www.google.com'))
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code works fine with HTTP page, but does not work with HTTPS, in my opinion it could be due to SSL issue.

So, please double check that your PyQt5 version have SSL support... ( You may find more information relative to download, install and setup openssl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516143/qt-ssl-support-missing))

> All that you need to do after downloading the SSL libraries is  to ensure
> that Qt can find where these openSSL libraries are located

Which OS do you use ?
PyQt5 was build with SSL support ?
Openssl is installed ?